# Update ItemsControl when an item in an ObservableCollection is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, itemscontrol

**The Problem:**

- You declare an `ItemsControl` ( or a control derived from `ItemsControl`) in the
  view.
- You bind the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel.
- Your view updates as expected when an item is added to /removed from the `ObservableCollection`.
- BUT, the view does not update when you change a property of an item in the `ObservableCollection`.

**Background:**

It seems that this is a common problem many WPF developers have encountered. It has been asked a few times:

[Notify ObservableCollection when Item changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes)

[ObservableCollection not noticing when Item in it changes (even with INotifyPropertyChanged)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop)

[ObservableCollection and Item PropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged)

**My Implementation:**

I tried to implement the accepted solution in [Notify ObservableCollection when Item changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes). The basic idea is to hook up a `PropertyChanged` handler in your MainWindowViewModel for each item in the `ObservableCollection`. When an item's property is changed, the event handler will be invoked and somehow the View is updated.

I could not get the implementation to work. Here is my implementation.

**ViewModels:**

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Item ViewModel:

```
class EmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _age;
    private string _name;

    public int Age 
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public string Name  
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} is {1} years old", Name, Age);
    }
}
```

Main Window ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> _collection;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _collection = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();
        _collection.CollectionChanged += MyItemsSource_CollectionChanged;

        AddEmployeeCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => AddEmployee());
        IncrementEmployeeAgeCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => IncrementEmployeeAge());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees 
    {
        get { return _collection; }
    }

    public ICommand AddEmployeeCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand IncrementEmployeeAgeCommand { get; set; }

    public void AddEmployee()
    {
        _collection.Add(new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                Age = 1,
                Name = "Random Joe",
            });
    }

    public void IncrementEmployeeAge()
    {
        foreach (var item in _collection)
        {
            item.Age++;
        }
    }

    private void MyItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:Iress.IosPlus.DynamicOE.Controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Command="{Binding AddEmployeeCommand}">Add Employee</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding IncrementEmployeeAgeCommand}">Increment Employee Age</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Employees[0]}"></TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"></ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**My Results:**

To verify my implementation, I create a view like so. The `TextBlock.Text` is bound to the first item in the collection. The `ItemsControl` is bound to the collection itself.

- Pressing the "Add Employee" button adds an `EmployeeViewModel` object in the collection and both the `TextBlock` and `ItemsControl` are updated as expected.
- Pressing the "Add Employee" again, the `ItemsControl` is updated with another entry. Great!
- Pressing the "Increment Employee Age" button. The `Age` property of each item is incremented by 1. The `PropertyChanged` event is raised. The `ItemPropertyChanged` event handler is invoked. The `Textblock` is updated as expected. However, the `ItemsControl` is not updated.

I am under the impression that the `ItemsControl` should be updated too when the `Employee.Age` is changed according to the answer in  [Notify ObservableCollection when Item changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes).

[image]

Comment: What are you even trying to do? An observable collection is observing the collection itself, not properties of the children. What is the benefit of doing a collection changed event if a child property changes?

Comment: @michael, I want the `ItemsControl` to refresh when an item in the collection is updated.

Comment: What would that accomplish though, all of the items in the collection are accounted for. Having the UI get the property won't change anything... the reference is still the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer using [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to debug XAML.

The issue is that you are trying to bind to the ToString() method and that does not raise the PropertyChanged event. If you look at the XAML bindings you will notice that the ObservableCollection is actually changing.

[image: Snoop Showing Correct Binding]

Now look at each item control and it's texts binding in the "Text" property. There are none, it's just text.

[image: Snoop showing no data binding to elements in the items control]

To fix this simply add an ItemsControl ItemTemplate with a DataTemplate that contains the elements you'd like to be displayed.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} is {1} years old">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="Age"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

We now have a green light on binding. RaisePropertyChanged is being called.

[image: Binding correctly shows green]

Ta-da!

[image: Solution shown]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a setter for the `Employees` property (the ObservableCollection) and called the `RaisePropertyChanged` in the setter. But it doesnot trigger the `ItemsControl` to update when pressing the increment employee age button.

Comment: Great answer. I understand using ItemTemplate to bind to the item's property can work around this problem. In fact, if you use the ItemTemplate, we do even need the handle the CollectionChanged event to hook up ItemPropertyChanged handler to each item. I think there might be a way to fix this without using the ItemTemplate. If no other answer is presented. I will mark yours as accepted.

Comment: @FrankLiu Declaring an ItemTemplate is the standard way of visualizing items in an ItemsControl or a derived control like ListBox. You may want to read the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Good eye, I didn't even notice OP was relying on the `.ToString()` to display the item! You're correct, the right way to do this would be to create a `Template` for displaying the item, and bind the UI elements to the properties so they react to change notifications. @FrankLiu If you'd like to avoid defining an `ItemTemplate` for your ItemsControl, you can also use an Implicit DataTemplate instead. It is a way of telling WPF that anytime it encounters an item of type `EmployeeViewModel` in the Visual Tree, it should render it using the template specified instead of the default .ToString()

Comment: @Rachel, I am confused now. If ItemTemplate/DateTemplate is the way to fix the problem. What is the purpose of handling the PropertyChanged event of each item? We dont even need to handle the CollectionChanged event in the `MainWindowViewModel` and all that plumbing.  I thought the problem in  [Notify ObservableCollection when Item changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes) is same as my problem.

Comment: @FrankLiu I think you're confusing the two and when they should be used. The DataTemplate is there to simply show what you ask XAML to show. It is not there to make sure that when your properties are updated it will update XAML as well. It doesn't care about that. As for the usage of INotifyPropertyChanged, you don't necessarily need it. You only need it when trying to make sure it will change in the UI when someone else modifies that property. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475130/why-use-inotifypropertychanged-with-bindings-in-wpf).

Comment: @AzzamAziz, I think misinterpreted the intention of Rachel's solution. It just provides a notification to the ViewModel, when an item is updated in the collection. The notification is not for UI to refresh the ItemsControl. Again, your answer is good. There are other ways to fix the problem, such as using DisplayMemberPath to update the view. Or subclass the ObservableCollection to generate a CollectionChanged event when Item PropertyChanged. Anyway, thanks for help everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work as you are not binding to a property but to a method which is ToString() To my knowledge that does not work. I'm curious as how your other solution may work though? Any links? Glad I could help. :)